# Asp.net connection

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have an asp.net website where thers an apply button and the webpage uses microsoft sql.  The problem is that when the user clicks the apply button for a very long time right about 80-100 times, the webpage usually seems to lose connection and takes forever trying to load the page, and then either says a connection is close or timeout error.

Any ideas?  Only happens if the user clicks the apply button for a very long time, but if i wait for like 2-5 mins and reopen the browser, everything works fine again

Comment: What part is timing out?  The connection from the client to the website?  The connection from the website to the database?  The processing of data in the code?  You're going to have to do some basic debugging to find where your rate bottleneck is, there's no way we can do that for you.

Comment: not even a single answer is accepted?

Comment: @user464111: And what's the error?  What are the steps to reproduce it?  Is there additional information available in the database logs?  Honestly, all of the text in this question boils down to, "It doesn't work, what's wrong?" and there's just no way we can answer that.

Comment: the only thing im doin is testing my webpage, i hit the apply button, it writes somtin to the database, and then i repeat this for like 80-100 times and thats when it seems to lose connecton to the database, either end up timeout connection or sayin that a connection is already close, but the thing is, im only hitting on button for that 80-100 times, nthing else

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the functionality by which use can click the button twice. Why don't you think of disabling the button once it is clicked and update the text to 'Processing.....'

You can do as follows...

Considering you have a button with ID="ButtonProcess" runat="server"

Add the script as following

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[id*=ButtonProcess]').click(function() {
                //Your logic goes here to change text, do validation, bla bla bla.....
                $('input[id*=ButtonProcess]').attr('className', 'processbookingbutton');
                $('input[id*=ButtonProcess]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    });
</script>
```

So, disabling the button and replacing the text with "Processing....." gives the user indication that you have already clicked the button and now wait for the output.
You can also use UpdatePanel and UpdateProgress controls to make it more user friendly.

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you aren't managing DbConnection properly.  Show us your data access code, specifically how you are opening/closing connections.